# How to evaluate the following definite integral?

Tags: definite-integrals

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{2 \pi}\int_0^{2 \pi} 
\frac{\cos\left(u\right) + \cos\left(v\right)-\cos\left(u\right)\cos\left(v\right)}{\,\sqrt{\,\left\{\vphantom{\LARGE A}2 \cos\left(u\right)\left[\cos\left(v\right)-1\right]-2\cos\left(v\right)+3 \right\}^{3}\,}\,}\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v
\end{equation}

I know the result is 1, because the above integral represent the linking number of 2 closed curves which in the pair diagram cross twice.
However, how to compute it analitically?

Comment: You missed $du$ and $dv$.

Comment: Random idea: try setting $u=s-t$ and $v=s+t$ and see if anything nice happens to the thing under the square root.

Comment: I know it might not be right but the answer I get from WolframAlpha is not 1.